# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4^n \over n} x^{2n+3}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{2^n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4^n \over n} x^{2n+3}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{2^n}$.

---

So for the first series I reached a conclusion but it seems wrong. I'm not sure to pinpoint where the problem is but my gut is telling me something isn't good.

Denote, we can split the sum into the even and odd series':

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4^n \over n} x^{2n+3} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty {4^{n-1} \over n-1} x^{2n+1} = {1 \over 2}(\sum_{n=4}^\infty (-1)^n {4^{n-1} \over n} x^{n}+\sum_{n=4}^\infty {4^{n-1} \over n} x^{n})$$

Now consider, $$a_n := {4^{n-1} \over n-1}$$

Then we have: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {4^n \over n} x^{2n+3} = {1 \over 2}(\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n a_n x^{n} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n x^{n})$$

Since limsup$|a_n| = \infty$, then from Cauchy-Hadamard theorem the radius of convergence is 0.

---

With the second series I'm just outright stuck. I tried to define $a_n := 2^n$, which seems like the only thing to do. Now if $A := \{a_n | n \in \mathbb {N} \}$, then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n x^{2^n} = \sum_{a \in A} a_n x^{a_n}$$

But the problem is I can't seem to turn it into a power series. I would love some help.

Comment: When you do the splitting, you need to adjust the $x$ powers. Also, you need to look at $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ and not $\limsup |a_n|$. In fact just note that $
\lim_{n \to  + \infty } \left| {\frac{{4^n }}{n}} \right|^{1/(2n + 3)}  = 2$.

Comment: @Gary thank you very much for the pointers. Is it ok now?

Comment: No it is not. $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{4^n }}{n}x^{2n + 3} }  = 2x^3 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{2n} }}{{2n}}x^{2n} }  = x^3 \left[ {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{2^n }}{n}x^n }  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^n }}{n}x^n } } \right]
$$ But you do not need to do this. Do you understand the concept of $\limsup$?

Comment: @Gary yes, it is the limit of the "biggest" sub-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach to determine the radius of convergence $r$ of the first series. We do not consider it as series with even powers $2n$ of $x$, but as series with powers $n$ of $x^2$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{n}x^{2n+3}=x^3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(4x^2\right)^n}{n}\tag{1}
=x^3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_ny^n
\end{align*}
According to the *[ratio test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius)*  the series (1) converges if
\begin{align*}
\phantom{\Longleftrightarrow\quad}\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\left|\frac{c_{n+1}y^{n+1}}{c_ny^n}\right|&<1\\
\Longleftrightarrow\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad |y|&< \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|\\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad\qquad\qquad\quad\left|4x^2\right|&<\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{n+1}{n}=1\\
\Longleftrightarrow\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\left|x\right|&<\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
from which we conclude $\color{blue}{r=\frac{1}{2}}$.

We write the second series as follows
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^nx^{2^n}=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}c_qx^q\qquad\qquad
\mathrm{with}\ c_q=
\begin{cases}
2^n&\qquad q=2^n\quad (n\geq 1)\\
0&\qquad\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Here it is convenient to use the $\limsup$ to determine the radius of convergence. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{r}=\underset{q\to\infty}{\limsup}\sqrt[q]{\left|c_q\right|}
=\underset{q=2^n\to\infty}{\lim}\sqrt[2^n]{2^n}=\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}2^{n/2^n}=1
\end{align*}
and we conclude $\color{blue}{r=1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MathStudent101: You're welcome. :-)